# Combine multiple UNIONS for a INSERT using ADO with ACE provider

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ado, adodb

I'm using Excel VBA and ADO (provider in connection string=ACE) to insert records into a sharepoint list.
I already have the code working fine - directly from Excel to Sharepoint - as long as I either:

1. Insert just one record, **or**
2. Use a loop to insert all records one-by-one

However, I want a faster operation.  I want to do something more along the lines of

```
insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3)
   select 'value1' as [col1],'value2' as [col2], 'value3' as [col3]
union all
   select 'value1' as [col1],'value2' as [col2], 'value3' as [col3]*
   ....etc etc
```

Apparently, when I use ACE as the provider (which is all I can do...I think?) then I am under Microsoft Access's less-than-useful "rules" for append queries.  There must be a From table, for example.  I've seen solutions that spoof out a "Dual" table to mimic oracle's functionality, but my whole objective is NOT to use Access - this is straight from Excel to Sharepoint, so creating and references Access Database files and Access Database Tables violates my goal.

Is there ANY way to convince ADO w/ACE to do any type of reasonably efficient bulk insert (I will be selecting values from spreadsheet cells, and I have no problem creating the VBA to create the SQL - I just need to know WHAT sql, if any, will actually work) ???

FYI, this is an example of my VBA code which works fine:

```
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://redacted.ad.redacted.com/sites/sitenameredacted/;LIST=Isaac Test Excel To Sharepoint;"
    .Open
End With

    mySQL = "insert into [Isaac Test Excel to Sharepoint] ([Column1],[Column2]) values ('col1_val1','col2_val2');"
```

Comment: Why cant you do one massive insert? As long as there arent >1500 lines for inserts, you should be able to concatenate each value chunks to the end of the sql statement. i.e. mySQL = mySQL & "(values, values, values), "

Comment: Yes, I have no problem coming up with the SQL - sql that works fine in, for example, SQL server.  But using ACE provider subjects me to MS Access rules - 1) can't do an insert without a From table/query

Comment: How does the ACE provider have anything to do with it? Youre obviously using ADO and you can easily do all sorts of things without forms/tables

Comment: The ACE provider has to do with it because that is the Microsoft Access engine, therefore, when you use the ACE provider, it subjects you to certain rules.
If you actually know the answer to this, please feel free to state what it is, rather than simply asserting repeatedly that it ought to work.  the fact is, with ADO and ACE provider, an Insert query without a From, simply doesn't work.  If you're familiar with the ACE provider, you know why, but that doesn't really matter for the question much.